# web host issue, .apk files to download from android browser

Tags: android, mime-types

I have been trying to get some people to test an android app and needed a friendly way to delivery it since it is not currently on the marketplace. I had uploaded it to my website and found that mostly every attempt to download failed. This was wither through the android emulator or actual devices.

I was only able to successfully download on 1 device personally and the rest of the users reported download unsuccessful/failed.

I put the file on 2 different webservers and and I was successfully able to download via android browser from the other servers.

What should I tell my primary host so I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 38):

They need to add the mine type for ".apk" to "`application/vnd.android.package-archive`"

I had a similar problem and fix it by adding the mime type to the site configuration in IIS. On Apache I haven't encountered the problem.